# Why is Greasemonkey javascript reporting an element has a class when web developer tools indicates that it doesnt seem to have

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a greasemonkey script that automtically presses a button on a page, but only if a tab is disabled, the tab shows duplicates records and when I inspect the page in firefox using Web Devloper Tools/Inspector I find that when we have duplicates records and the tab is enabled that we have

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="duplicates-tab" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false"><a href="#duplicates-tab" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">Release Duplicates</a></li>
```

but when it is disabled i have

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-state-disabled" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="duplicates-tab" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="true"><a href="#duplicates-tab" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">Release Duplicates</a></li>
```

i.e when disabled the enclosing list element of the link has an additional *ui-state-disabled* class (this was the only difference I could find when i inspected the html)

So I write my greasemonkey script as follows

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     AutoContinueAddRelease
// @version  
// @grant    none
// @include  https://musicbrainz.org/release/add
// ==/UserScript==
window.addEventListener ("load", Greasemonkey_main, false);

function Greasemonkey_main () 
{
  var as = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for(a of as)
  {
    if(a.href=='https://musicbrainz.org/release/add#duplicates-tab')
    {
      alert(a.parentElement.classList);  
      if(a.parentElement.classList.contains('ui-state-disabled'))
      {
        var button = document.getElementById("enter-edit");   
        if(button!=null)
        {
          button.click();
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

But in both cases it finds the *ui-state-disabled* class and submits the form, which is not what i want, I dont understand why.

Comment: Other javascript on the page may remove that class once the page is loaded. Your javascript is seeing the class before that happens.

Comment: Why do you use the load event?  I would use [`@run-at`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_run_at) instead, if anything but the default is necessary..

Comment: @ceving i was just trying it based on another stackoveflow post, removed it now but made no difference.

Comment: @Ouroborus thanks I think you are  right, got it working by adding setTimeout(), this is my first greasmonkey script so if you have any suggestions on improvements feel free to comment

Comment: Use `curl` to fetch the raw HTML and inspect it, in order to find out, if the class gets modified by any JavaScript. If it gets modified, you need to use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Did this already in Tampermonkey and it works fine.

Comment: Using a timeout may be less reliable, because you do not know how long the page initialization takes.

Comment: @ceving ok assuming it does (it must be right), coulf you post a modified script using this i will mark as right answer.

Comment: Sorry do not have an account there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by setting timeout to delay running the script until a bit after page loaded based on @Ourobirus comment

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     AutoContinueAddRelease
// @version  
// @grant    none
// @include  https://musicbrainz.org/release/add
// ==/UserScript==
setTimeout(check, 5000);
function check()
{
  var as = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for(a of as)
  {
    if(a.href=='https://musicbrainz.org/release/add#duplicates-tab')
    {
      if(a.parentElement.classList.contains('ui-state-disabled'))
      {
        var button = document.getElementById("enter-edit");   
        if(button!=null)
        {
          button.click();
        }        
      }
      else
      {
          alert('duplicatesFound');
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```